# posting to Facebook page wall as page itself with no user session

Tags: php, facebook, api, curl

This is my first question here, so apologies if asking something trivial - though I didn't find an answer after an hour of digging.

I have a PHP website which needs to connect with a Facebook page in the following method:
On certain triggers, the site needs to post to the page's wall *as the page itself*. This has to be done automatically, even if no user session is available (e.g. if someone uses the site without actually having a Facebook account).

I found solutions using extended token expiration times (offline access), but in those cases, the post will always appear as the site admin (me, in this case). However, I need the post to be written by the page. When using Facebook as the page, I have no right to request an offline access token.

Is this even possible at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cache the page access token on your server and use that to make the updates - the page login is pretty well documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/ -

Store the `access_token` in your server-side code and use that token to post as the page - the page access token won't expire if you have a long-expiry access token for the page admin, unless the user stops being an admin of the page, removes the app, etc.